# Xcode 4 final - How to delete book mark in documentation?

Tags: xcode

You can book mark a help document through Editor-> Add bookmark.
But how to delete it?

Might be simple but I cannot find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Highlight it, and then use the delete (backspace) button. The one at the top right of your keyboard

Comment: You are right. But the delete key at the right near "fn" and "end" doesn't work. The one right to "=" works. Strange, Physically the key is good because both work on textedit.

Comment: That is because the key you're talking about is on the larger keyboards is the forward delete button rather than the traditional backwards delete button which is used to delete things on Macs.